# SQL Server Management Objects (SMO) - Login failed for user.Error on production server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, smo

I have written a code which take backup of database (Generate Sql script) on button click, This code is **working fine on localhost**, However when i deploy this to production i get the following error.

> Login failed for user 'XXXXXX\IWPD_1257(XXXXX)'

A part of Stack Trace is

```
[ConnectionFailureException: Failed to connect to server ..]
   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.DatabaseCollection.get_Item(String name) +370
   LeadWeb.Backup.scriptTables() +232
   LeadWeb.Backup.btnsubmit_OnClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) +5
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9628114
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

Here is my code

```
public void scriptTables()
        {
            try
            {
                string folder = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Excels/data.sql");// I have this file 
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(folder, string.Empty);
                Server myServer = new Server(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["server"]);
                Database CMSDB = myServer.Databases[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Database"]];

                Scripter script = new Scripter(myServer);
                ScriptingOptions so = new ScriptingOptions();
                so.AnsiPadding = true;
                so.IncludeHeaders = true;
                so.Default = true;
                so.DriForeignKeys = true;
                so.DriPrimaryKey = true;
                so.DriUniqueKeys = true;
                so.ScriptData = true;
                so.ScriptSchema = true;
                so.ScriptDrops = false;


                StringBuilder ss = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (Table table in CMSDB.Tables)
                {
                    string tables = table.Name;
                    string filename = folder;

                    so.FileName = filename;
                    so.AppendToFile = true;
                    CMSDB.Tables[tables].EnumScript(so);
                }
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                    "attachment; filename=" + "LeadBackup" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("d") + ".sql");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", folder.Length.ToString());
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(folder);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                Response.Write(e.Message);
            }
```

Webconfig values

`<add key="Server" value="." /> // changes according to server
 <add key="Database" value="Lead" /> // changes according to Database`

Any help or guidance.?

Comment: Where is the actual message? You posted only part of the stack trace but omitted the actual message and any inner exceptions. This doesn't help. Also, are the database and server names correct? Are you trying to connect to the wrong server perhaps? Are you connecting to a named instance? Did you check SQL Server's logs?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for comment , i solved my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your database connection string is using integrated security, and XXXXXX\IWPD_1257(XXXXX) is not configured to access the database server and/or the database.

In SSMS, go to security > logins and identify the windows groups that have access to the server.  In active directory, add XXXXXX\IWPD_1257(XXXXX) to one of those groups.

Alternately, you can directly add XXXXXX\IWPD_1257(XXXXX) as a login.

Regardless of the approach, make sure the group or user is also added to the database security and granted access to the roles required to query from the tables you need.

Comment: Yes you are right , On localhost i am using `Integrated Security=True` but on production (Shared server) its `False`

Comment: In production, your connection string still needs to provide a security context.  If you do not want to use windows based security, you can create a sql account and password, and put that user/pw in the connection string.  If you go this route, you should encrypt the connection string.

Comment: I think I get your point , So I have to provide Username and password for database in order to access(for production) , right?

Comment: If you are using a SQL account.  If you are using windows security, then you do not need to specify user/password in the connection string; you would just use integrated security.  When you use windows authentication, you just need to ensure that the user has access to the server and database as described above.

Answer (score 0):

As @jim said it was Authentication issue, I did't provided the Login Id and Password for the SQL Server, After some researched i able to manage to done it right, i am posting code for future reference.Hope it will help someone :)

```
public void scriptTables()
        {
            try
            {
                string folder = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Excels/data.sql");// I have this file 
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(folder, string.Empty);

                ServerConnection serverConnection = new ServerConnection();
                serverConnection.LoginSecure = false;
                serverConnection.ServerInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"];
                serverConnection.Login = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmoUser"];
                serverConnection.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmoPass"];
                serverConnection.DatabaseName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Database"];

                Server myServer = new Server(serverConnection);
                Database CMSDB = myServer.Databases[ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Database"]];


                Scripter script = new Scripter(myServer);
                ScriptingOptions so = new ScriptingOptions();
                so.AnsiPadding = true;
                so.IncludeHeaders = true;
                so.Default = true;
                so.DriForeignKeys = true;
                so.DriPrimaryKey = true;
                so.DriUniqueKeys = true;
                so.ScriptData = true;
                so.ScriptSchema = true;
                so.ScriptDrops = false;
                script.Options = so;

                StringBuilder ss = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (Table table in CMSDB.Tables)
                {
                    string tables = table.Name;
                    foreach (string s in script.EnumScript(new Urn[] { table.Urn }))
                        ss.Append(s);
                }
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(folder, ss.ToString());
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
                    "attachment; filename=" + "LeadBackup" + DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("d") + ".sql");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", folder.Length.ToString());
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(folder);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Response.Write(e.Message);
            }
        }
```